# Left Shift in C++ - Unexpected Result

Tags: c++

Issue:  `uint32_t entry = (uint16_t )1 << (bitPosition && 0xf);`

I'm about to code a memory allocator that uses a bit map in order to track allocated/free pages.

```
     void
PageAllocator::deallocate( uintptr_t memoryAddress )
{
logInfoEvent_m( "function = %s, file = %s, line = %i.",
                __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
                __FILE__,
                __LINE__
              );

uint32_t    pageNb      = memoryAddress / memory::pageSize_c;
uint32_t    index       = pageNb / bitsPerBitmapEntry_c;
uint32_t    bitPosition = pageNb % bitsPerBitmapEntry_c;

uint32_t    entry       = (uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition && 0x0f);
__pageAllocatorBitmap[index] = ((uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition && 0x0f));

logInfoEvent_m( "  ____freeing page: address = 0x%*x; pageNb = %d; index = %d; bit position = %d; entry = %d; bit map entry 0x%*x.",
```

During initialization the function is called for all available pages. I'm getting following result:

```
    index = 1; bit position = 0; entry = 1; bit map entry 0x00000001.
```

but for this line the result is incorrect:

```
    index = 1; bit position = 5; entry = 2; bit map entry 0x00000002.
```

For position with value 0 the result is correct.
For any other value that position holds the value for entry is "2" which is not correct.
My expectation for position = 5 is entry = 32 decimal (0x20).

Environment:
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30

I have been reading previous post, but all the hints I found there where not helping to solve the problem. I know, that shifting beyond 32-bit is unpredictable.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong here. Sorry for disturbing the community.

Comment: Should be `&` not `&&` for bit manipulation ?

Answer (score 3):

*entry* and *__pageAllocatorBitmap[index]* can only value 1 or 2 because `bitPosition && 0xf` is a boolean expression valuing 0 or 1, so you can only get 1 (`1 << 0`) or 2 (`1 << 1`)

you want to shift depending on the 4 lower bits of *bitPosition*, so just replace

> ```
> uint32_t entry = (uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition && 0xf);
> __pageAllocatorBitmap[index] = ((uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition && 0x0f));
> ```

by

```
uint32_t entry = (uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition & 0xf);
__pageAllocatorBitmap[index] = ((uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition & 0x0f));
```

or

```
uint32_t entry = (uint32_t )1 << (bitPosition & 0xf);
__pageAllocatorBitmap[index] = entry;
```